# jQuery IF statement not working?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying for so long but I just can't get the if statement to work. I'm assuming it's a syntax error but I haven't been able to find it when comparing to all of the tutorials and other SO questions.

The end result will be: If the form action is "add_task.php" I want the jQuery to get the contents of another file and prepend it to a specified div.

The alert message is there at the moment as a troubleshooting measure.

Everything that falls under 'else' works fine, it's just the 'if' part that won't run.

```
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr("action");
        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(action, dataString, function(action){
            if(action == "add_task.php"){
                alert("Add!");
            }else{
                $(event.target).closest(".task_container").load("display_edit.php");
            }
        });                 
    });
```

Comment: Point of note: it's a JS `if` statement, not a jQuery one. jQuery is JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closure variable and the callback parameter named as `action`, I think what you need is to check whether the url to which the request was submitted was `add_task.php` in that case rename the callback param to something else

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr("action");
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.post(action, dataString, function(data){
        if(action == "add_task.php"){
            alert("Add!");
        }else{
            $(event.target).closest(".task_container").load("display_edit.php");
        }
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Ah, that worked, I understand now! The alert is showing up fine, but I'm now having trouble getting the code to prepend. What i have contained in my if statement now is `code` $.get("display_edit.php", function(data){$(data).prepend("#add");}); `code`

Comment: you need to use `$(data).prependTo("#add");}` or `$("#add").prepend(data);}`

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I've now got it to the point where it seems the document I'm getting isn't outputting any data.

Comment: which part is failing?

Comment: It seems that I've misunderstood how to retrieve the last inserted id. Essentially I want $_SESSION['task']['id'] to contain the last id inserted into the task table.//edit: Finally got it to work! :) Thank-you for your help.